# Parallel Quest #53: "Dangerous Duo! Warriors Never Rest" bonus objective 2

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

I'm currently going through all of the PQs trying to complete all of their bonus objectives. I seem to be at an impasse with this particular PQ however.

The objectives are as follows:

- Recover 3 Dragon Balls (primary)
- Defeat Broly with Gohan surviving
- Get 7 Dragon Balls

The primary objective is easy. No problems there. Defeating Broly with Gohan alive? Not so much, but for all the wrong reasons. For starters, in this particular PQ Broly is a **moron**. He's perfectly content to simply fly around the COM players in circles, occasionally firing off some token Ki blasts while getting pummelled by the allies that I can't avoid getting.

In order to get Gohan to appear you need to allow Broly to KO Videl followed by Goten and Trunks (Kid). Videl goes down like a sack of potatoes, but the other two don't. Even with me *bringing zero allies **and** not assisting in any way, at any point in the fight*, Broly (usually) barely survives against those two, however he's often so badly injured that Gohan simply has to breathe on him and he's KO'd.

All that I can find to do after Broly is down is blow up some buildings and return the 3 Dragon Balls that make up the primary objective, which promptly ends the PQ.

Which leaves me with my problem: how do I activate the final bonus objective?

Comment: Since posting this, Broly has twice failed to survive Goten and Trunks. This is *supposed* to be a 7-star difficulty quest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been awhile since I played, but the way I remember this working is that the Ultimate Finish, IE, the extra step to occur, is completely random in most cases.

So, for this stage, activating the final objective, simply has a CHANCE to occur when you Defeat broly and turn in the first 3 dragonballs.

So, you need to defeat broly, then turn in the 3 dragonablls. If Broly doesnt revive, you didnt get lucky. Keep doing it until it happens.

At that point, Broly is stronger and you can let him beat videl and the kids, or, If you just defeat Broly in this revived form BEFORE Gohan dies(Which includes him never showing up), I THINK, you get credit for number 2. To be safe, you can let Broly beat everybody up while you gather 3 of the remaning 4 dragonballs. Then, wait until broly beats up the two kids, and when Gohan appears, finish him off.

Comment: The issue I was having is that 95% of the time Broly got KO'd by the two kids *without me helping at all at any point*. That said, I did eventually manage to get it done, must have taken me a good 40 goes before I got lucky though. That said, this seems to be to be the most feasible answer, so +1.

Comment: I believe, if the ultimate finish happens, Broly revives and is much more aggressive and "helpful" in this regard. Which is the way its intended to happen I think, trying to do it before is rather difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Gohan doesn't have to appear.  I have gotten the ultimate finish without that.

Comment: Could you possibly expand upon that? Was there anything in particular that you did to trigger the second bonus objective?

Answer (score -1):

I beat Broly before Videl died and got ultimate finish.

Comment: While this is handy to know, it's not really an answer